# Render crisp text using Canvas.drawText in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm doing an AppWidget and in its settings I'm letting the user enable/disable text shadow. Since I can't invoke the shadow method through the RemoteViews class, I'm doing a "draw" method that dynamically paints the widget and its container.

When drawing the text though, it gets kinda blurred and not that crisp like when using a TextView. The only code I've used for the text painting is:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setAntiAlias(true);
p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Are there any other magic I need to do for it to become more crisp?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
```

did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

These are my text paint settings:

```
    textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    textPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
    textPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
```

Seems to be working well for me.

Comment: Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG); did the trick for me

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will try it out and see if my text looks better now. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `text` `setAntiAlias(true)` **(In Hardware mode)** only works from API 18 and above so use this code to set your layer type.

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
```

Comment: False. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setAntiAlias(boolean)
This has been in the sdk since API level 1

Comment: @Tomas Please check my edited answer. As in API 18 they stopped AntiAlias feature in software layer.

Comment: Ah, yes. For future reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported